# Delivery Optimization constantly using up to 80 % CPU

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v2004

For the past 4 or 5 days, Windows service `Delivery Optimization` (display name) / `DoSvc` (service name) has been constantly consuming up to 80 % of the CPU. Sometimes the CPU usage is fairly consistent and other times it's "spikey". Sometimes there's associated network activity and sometimes there's not.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thus far, I have tried all of the following but nothing has made a difference:

1. Stopping the service but it times out with error message `The Delivery Optimization service could not be stopped`.
2. Killing the service's process ID but doing so fails with error message `ERROR: The process with PID 80788 could not be terminated. Reason: Access is denied.`, even when doing so as `LOCAL SYSTEM` / `nt authority\system`.
   [image]
3. Rebooting the PC.
4. Disabling it via Settings → Update & Security → Delivery Optimisation.
5. Pausing Windows updates via Settings → Update & Security → Windows Update.
6. Setting my NIC as metered via Settings → Network & Internet → <my NIC> → Properties.
7. Checked the event logs "Application" and "System" but found nothing regular or relevant.

I don't know if it's relevant but my PC's RAM usage has also been strange: [3.13 GB RAM missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1578565/3-13-gb-ram-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Googled "windows 10 delivery optimization logs" and found https://petri.com/troubleshoot-windows-update-delivery-optimization which led me to its PowerShell commandlets.

After some experimentation, I executed `Get-DeliveryOptimizationStatus -Verbose | Format-List Status,Priority,SourceURL,DownloadDuration,TotalBytesDownloaded` which outputted the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-DeliveryOptimizationStatus -Verbose | Format-List Status,Priority,SourceURL,DownloadDuration,TotalBytesDownloaded
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' with following parameters, ''namespaceName' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DeliveryOptimization,'className' = MSFT_DeliveryOptimizationFile'.
VERBOSE: Operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' complete.


Status                      : Caching
Priority                    : Foreground
SourceURL                   : https://clientupdates.dropboxstatic.com/dbx-releng/dropbox_passwords/win/DropboxPasswords_beta.appinstaller
DownloadDuration            : 10:14:42.1920000
TotalBytesDownloaded        : 50549400

Status                      : Paused
Priority                    : Background
SourceURL                   :
DownloadDuration            : 00:00:00
TotalBytesDownloaded        : 0

Status                      : Downloading
Priority                    : Foreground
SourceURL                   : https://clientupdates.dropboxstatic.com/dbx-releng/dropbox_passwords/win/DropboxPasswords_1.1.27.appx
DownloadDuration            : 16:13:46.5660000
TotalBytesDownloaded        : 70817815424



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

[image]

I expected to see something related to Microsoft, not entries solely related to Dropbox Passwords, one of which being a download that's lasted **16+ hours** and downloaded **65.95 GB**! The entire app is only supposed to be 161 MB!

[image]

Dropbox Passwords aligns with the timeline as I installed it on [the day of announcement (2020/08/12)](https://twitter.com/Dropbox/status/1293588304806334464) or the day after (2020/08/13) which I roughly recall is when this problem started.

I uninstalled the app via Settings → Apps → Apps & features but the issue didn't subside and `Get-DeliveryOptimizationStatus` still reported the same.

I rebooted my PC and found that:

1. **The problem had almost entirely subsided**. The process is still running but it's now only consuming ~12 % of the CPU which may well be normal.
2. For the first few minutes, `Get-DeliveryOptimizationStatus` reported no activities.
3. After a few minutes, `Get-DeliveryOptimizationStatus` reported two activities, both Dropbox Passwords but both paused.
4. Settings → Apps → Apps & features reported that Dropbox Passwords was installed again so I uninstalled it again.
5. `Get-DeliveryOptimizationStatus` is still reporting all activites paused.

Comment: Thank you! I had been wrestling with Delivery Optimization using my CPU for weeks. I tried editing the registry as per https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-delivery-optimization-wont-turn-off-in-windows-10, only to have it come back after a few days. Have you reported it as a bug? If so I would like to go to that site and make sure they know it is not an isolated incident.

Comment: @By137 I'm glad to hear that this was helpful to you. Yes, I have reported it to them via Twitter which they acknowledged.