# 3.13 GB RAM missing

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v2004

Lately, I've noticed that my PC has constantly been using ~90 % of my 8 GB of RAM even when I'm not doing anything particularly intensive.

Today, I noticed that the general vs per-process figures don't match up: there's a 3,283,600 K (3.13 GB) discrepancy. This can be seen in the following Task Manager and RamMap screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Things I've read online say that "Process Private" just means that it's being used by a single process and to check the tab "Processes" but, as you can see, I've already done that and found nothing helpful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I don't know if it's related but my PC's CPU usage has also been strange: [Delivery Optimization constantly using up to 75 % of CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1578557/delivery-optimization-consuming-25-to-75-of-cpu)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s memory performance view.

Comment: @DanielB I've added them, as requested. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem.  It looks to me like all memory is present or accounted for.

Comment: You have high non-paged pool and very high paged pool usage.

Comment: @Mark How do you figure? I have 7.9 GB but all of the values in the Task Manager screenshot add up to 2461.9 MB and all of the values in the RamMap screenshot add up to 3,449,862 KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since I resolved the root cause of my CPU usage problem ([Delivery Optimization constantly using up to 80 % CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1578557/delivery-optimization-constantly-using-up-to-80-cpu?noredirect=1&lq=1)), my baseline RAM usage has been ~4.8 GB / ~60 % which is what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to differing definitions of "in use".

"Process private" is basically RAM that's been assigned to a program for its exclusive use.  I think that the difference between the "Task Manager" and "RamMap" numbers for individual programs comes down to Task Manager not counting RAM if it's a strong candidate for swapping out if needed.

"Mapped file" refers to [memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), one way of loading a file into memory.  The machine code of every program you're running is loaded this way, as are many data files.  Because this data can freely be discarded and re-loaded as needed, neither Task Manager nor RamMap counts it as "in use".

"Sharable" refers to DLLs and other shared data.  Since this memory is shared between programs, it doesn't show up in any one program's usage.

Everything in the RamMap listing between "Page Table" and "Kernel Stack" refers to memory used by the operating system itself.  Like shared memory, this isn't assigned to any one program, so it doesn't show up in the per-program usage.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's good to know.